# Unable to convert date format like 12-Oct-2021 to date in Node,js

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, datejs

I'm trying to convert dates in the format like 12-Oct-2021, 15-Nov-2021 etc to dates in Node.JS

I tried using the moments library like this:

```js
const getStartEndWeek = (stringArray) => {
  const d = new Date();
  let year = d.getFullYear()
  let startWeek = stringArray[0] +'-'+ year;
  let endWeek = stringArray[1] +'-'+ year;
  let startWeekDate = moment(startWeek);
  let endWeekDate = moment(endWeek);

  return [startWeekDate,endWeekDate] 
}
```

However, it keeps returning a warning:

```
Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format.
```

What is the way around this?

Comment: Provide the correct format when parsing your date. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/

Comment: resolved: used moment(startWeek,'DD-MMM-YYYY')